# How to add key-value pair like dictionary?

Tags: r, list, for-loop, missing-data

My data (total 8532 obs) look like this:

```
Prd_Id  Weight
DRA24   19.35
DRA24   NA
DRA24   NA
DRA24   19.35
DRA24   19.35
DRA59   8.27
DRA59   8.27
DRA59   8.27
DRA59   8.27
DRA59   NA
DRA59   NA
```

Basically the problem is that there are many pairs of `Prd_id` and `weight` and in them some of the `Prd_id` doesnt have `weight` mentioned for example I have shown in the data that first has but 2nd and 3rd doesn't so I know the value of `weight` and I just have to replace NA with it, all identical `Prd_id` will have same `weight` but in R there is no such thing like a dictionary so I am finding it difficult to fix this problem. I tried using `for loop` but it is taking a very long time, my code looks like this:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(bms)){
  for(j in 1:1555){
    if(spl$Prd_Id[j]==bms$Prd_Id[i]){
      bms$weight[i]=spl$weight[j]
    }
  }
}
```

`bms` is the whole `data` (8532 obs) and `spl` (1555 obs) is a subset of `bms` with uniques values of `Prd_Id`.

Comment: It is unclear why a dictionary is the preferred solution to missing values. You could simply remove (`complete.cases`) or impute them (several packages provide that). If it's a lookup you need from a `data.frame` (as you've shown here), you could use one of the "join" operators (whether `merge` in base R, one of the `dplyr::*_join` functions, or the equivalent in `data.table`). If `spl` is merely a sampling of `bms` but it has missing values (that are present in `bms`), your problem is *not* a dictionary, your problem is your sampling technique.

Comment: Actually there are many pairs of Prd_id and weight and in them some of the Prd_id doesnt have weight mentioned for eg like I have shown in the data that first has but 2nd and 3rd doesn't so I know the value of weight and i just have to replace NA with it, all identical Prd_id will have same weight thats why I was thinking of creating a dictionary which will have key as the Prd_id and value as the weight. Secondally spl doesn't have missing value it has all the unique values of Prd_id and corresponding weights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @r2evans suggested you could use a SQL-like join strategy, combined with dplyr's `coalesce`this would look something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

# create 'bms'.
bms <- data_frame(
  Prd_Id = c("DRA24", "DRA24", "DRA24", "DRA24", "DRA24", "DRA59", "DRA59", "DRA59", "DRA59", "DRA59", "DRA59"),
  Weight = c(19.35, NA, NA, 19.35, 19.35, 8.27, 8.27, 8.27, 8.27, NA, NA)
)

# create 'spl'
spl <- bms %>% filter(!is.na(Weight)) %>% filter(!duplicated(Prd_Id))

# SQL-like join and coalesce strategy
res <- bms %>% 
  left_join(spl, by = "Prd_Id", suffix = c("_bms", "_spl")) %>% 
  mutate(Weight = coalesce(Weight_bms, Weight_spl)) %>%
  select(-Weight_bms, -Weight_spl)
```

Comment: Thanks, left_join was what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

No need for a `left_join`:

```
bms %>% 
  group_by(Prd_Id) %>% 
  mutate(Weight = Weight[!is.na(Weight)][1])
```

another way with `first`:

```
bms %>% 
  group_by(Prd_Id) %>% 
  mutate(Weight = first(Weight[!is.na(Weight)]))
```

The result:

```
# A tibble: 11 x 2
# Groups:   Prd_Id [2]
   Prd_Id Weight
    <chr>  <dbl>
 1  DRA24  19.35
 2  DRA24  19.35
 3  DRA24  19.35
 4  DRA24  19.35
 5  DRA24  19.35
 6  DRA59   8.27
 7  DRA59   8.27
 8  DRA59   8.27
 9  DRA59   8.27
10  DRA59   8.27
11  DRA59   8.27
```

Off course you can do this in vanilla R also:

```
transform(bms, Weight = ave(Weight, Prd_Id, FUN = function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1]))
```

The result is the same:

```
   Prd_Id Weight
1   DRA24  19.35
2   DRA24  19.35
3   DRA24  19.35
4   DRA24  19.35
5   DRA24  19.35
6   DRA59   8.27
7   DRA59   8.27
8   DRA59   8.27
9   DRA59   8.27
10  DRA59   8.27
11  DRA59   8.27
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution

```
# example data
bms <- data.frame(
  Prd_Id = c("DRA24", "DRA24", "DRA24", "DRA24", "DRA24", "DRA59", "DRA59", "DRA59", "DRA59", "DRA59", "DRA59"),
  Weight = c(19.35, NA, NA, 19.35, 19.35, 8.27, 8.27, 8.27, 8.27, NA, NA)
)

# create key-value pairs
spl <- unique(bms[!is.na(bms[,"Weight"]),])
spl <- setNames(spl[,"Weight"], spl[,"Prd_Id"])

# fill NAs
idx <- which(is.na(bms[,"Weight"]))
bms[idx,"Weight"] <- spl[bms[idx, "Prd_Id"]]
```